# os x server and remote git repos

Tags: git, continuous-integration, remote-server, osx-server

Can someone explain the relationship between Xcode developer computer, the osx server and using a remote git repository?

I want to commit my changes to a remote repo(bitbucket) and have my os x server run the bots on it?

new:
After some messing around, I have managed to make a bot for the remote server but now I get the following errors

```
    SSH Known Hosts file path is located at /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/ssh_known_hosts
SSH strict host checking is disabled (you can enable this by editing the SSHStrictHostKeyChecking key in /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist
Untrusted HTTPS certificates is enabled (you can disable this by editing the TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates key in /Library/Server/Xcode/Config/xcsbuildd.plist
622a6bc3406c764e9e97ec156818b739ecb40ee9 refs/heads/master
```

only I did that already and it doesn't change anything.

and another error:

```
xcodebuild: error: The project 'testOnlineGit3' does not contain a scheme named 'testOnlineGit3.xcscheme'.
```

My scheme is shared, and thats its name, so I'm not sure how to fix it

new: Changed my scheme name, and now the bot works, but i still get the previous warnings, I'm not sure exactly what they mean, anyone has an idea how to make them go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if understood your question correctly but:
Xcode server can connect to remote repository like (bitbucket, github etc..).
Basically you submit your code to remote repo and Xcode server will pull your submitted code.

Comment: can i program and run bots on it?

Comment: On what? Bots are run/configured on Xcode server? Have you checked manual it's pretty easy to setup.

Comment: Yes, I have read and followed the instructions about setting up bots, but as far as the guide says, they are set up from xcode under product-add bot, not the os x server, have I missed something? P.S sorry for being so unclear, its the first time I ever deal with setting up servers

Comment: Not necessary, you can bot directly from ci server after it's started,
http://tinypic.com/r/2imb9f8/5

Answer (score 3):

[This website](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2013/10/xcode-bots-common-problems-and-workarounds/) gives details on how to get Xcode continuous integration set up with remote Git repositories.  Specifically, when setting up the bot in Xcode, DO NOT check "Integrate immediately."  Then when it asks you how to log in to the Git repository in question, you MUST choose "login as guest."  Then on the OS X Server, launch the "Server" app, click on the "Xcode" service to configure it, click the "Repositories" tab, and under the Remote Repositories section you should see a new entry created for the repository you just added.  It will look like "git@somehost.com:RepoName"  Select it and click the Edit (pencil) button, and under Authentication, choose "SSH Key."  Fill in the username you use to connect to your remote Git repository (most likely "git"), and under the "SSH Key" section click the "Edit" button and fill in the public and private SSH keys you use to log in to the remote Git repository.  Finally, after all this is done, go back to Xcode to the bot you created, and click the "Integrate Now" button and all should work as advertised.

Comment: As of Xcode 6/Server 4.0, this answer is outdated. It works completely differently (and even more opaquely) now.

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.3, when creating a new Bot Xcode will check the credentials for your repository and any submodule and report those that fail to authenticate.

You can then chose to enter a login/password, or better yet specify an existing SSH key or create a new one. You just keep the user as `git`.

I could use my existing keys pair for GitHub but had to create a new one for BitBucket (and add the public key through their website).